# Apache & MySQL aren't working on xampp control panel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, ssl

I installed xampp on my PC but can't start Apache & MySQL from xampp control panel. This error always appears:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
```

This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums

I tried everything to solve it, and also changed the port but nothing helped, this error always appears.

Here is the apache log error:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:warn] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[core:notice] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6128
[ssl:warn] [pid 6128:tid 600] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:warn] [pid 6128:tid 600] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6128:tid 600] (OS 109)‏‏פעולת הצינור הסתיימה.  : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent
[mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 4560:tid 704] AH00427: Parent: child process 6128 exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

Please help me, this is a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to uncheck the “`Enable LMHOSTS Lookup`” box in the `TCP/IP` protocol setup (under WINS setting). Here are the steps to do this:

1. Open “Control Panel” then “Network Connections.”
2. Right-click on “Local Area Connection” and select “Properties.”
3. Double-click on the “Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)” line to open the
   “Properties.”
4. On the “General” tab, click the “Advanced” button.
5. Select the “WINS” tab and uncheck the “Enable LMHOSTS Lookup” box.”

http://www.jennyconnors.com/computers/installing-apache2-and-the-wsasocket-failed-to-open-the-inherited-socket-error

Comment: Just check if windows firewall is blocking?

Comment: Windows firewall is disabled.

Comment: configure apache on a different port other than what it's configured right now (may be default 80) OR  try Not to install apache as a service..if it's installed as a service you can use sc delete [service name] to delete the service..

Comment: I already tried to  configure apache on a different port other than 80 but it didn't help as well. What do you mean by "install apache as a service"? How can I check if it's installed as a service?

Comment: 13:15:57  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:15:57  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
13:15:57  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:15:57  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:15:57  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: I typed services.msc, Apache2.4 appears there, but it isn't activated, it's stopped.

Comment: If I try to activate Apache2.4 via services.msc, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760628/why-wont-apache-start-in-xampp-installation

Comment: I still get the port 80 error even though I already changed the port to 8080.

Comment: The process who uses port 80 is System. I can't stop it via processes tab in task manager. But I changed the port to 8080 and still the same error appears. What to do? :(

Comment: Go to services.msc >> right click world wide web publishing >> stop service and try restarting Apache

Comment: I don't see world wide web publishing there.

Comment: I tried everything I could but nothing helped, the same error appears.

Comment: Detail discussion of the causes is here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,80320

Comment: Run as an Admin and try again.