# error running apache after xampp install

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I installed xampp on win7 and get this error when starting apache.
I unchecked skype and nothing changes.
How do I find what is using port 80? How do I fix this please.
I dont have another server running.

```
update this is the error. I click on start and  get this problem
    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:27:19 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:27:19 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:27:19 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:27:19 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:27:19 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:27:19 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

The below link didnt help me

[Why won't Apache start in XAMPP installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760628/why-wont-apache-start-in-xampp-installation)

Here is the error log

```
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:53.823331 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6048:tid 236] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:54.084345 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6048:tid 236] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:55.240412 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6048:tid 236] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:55.241412 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6048:tid 236] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:55.241412 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6048:tid 236] AH00094: Command line: 'E:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:55.339417 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6048:tid 236] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1840
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:55.950452 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1840:tid 248] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:56.202467 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1840:tid 248] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jun 07 22:36:56.299472 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1840:tid 248] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: I dont see any ention of apache in that errpor

Comment: have you tried running it as admin?

Comment: Yes sorry I copied wrong error code as now it is apache.running what in admin? It is just my local pc

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try those methods, it should work:

- quit/exit **Skype** (make sure it's not running) because it reserves localhost:80
- disable Anti-virus (Try first to disable skype and running again, if it didn't work do this step)
- Right click on xampp control panel and run as administrator

Comment: I am really stuck here. I just installed xampp after uninstalling easyphp and I dont have skype and I dont see any apache service to start? I have xamp control panel which will give an error on start

Comment: @ajt did you try to disable anti virus then running apache server ?

Comment: usually it's not. Keep anti-virus and skype disabled and try to right click on xampp control panel and run as administrator @ajt

Comment: it works now after reboot and run as admin. Is there a way to run not as admin? i want auto startup

Comment: @ajt go to control panel > sercices -> right click and change manual to automatic or something like that I don't remember 100% the options

Comment: skype never interfered in running apache server. but today it just wouldn't start. Thanks a lot @Amir

Comment: To run Apache & Skype side to side: Skype -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection -> Remove check on "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections"

Comment: All suggestion not work for me. Is it because of 64 bit window version or not?

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, I solved changing the ports. 

-> Clicked button **Config** front of Apache.
1) Select **Apache (httpd.conf)**
2) searched for this line: **Listen 80** 
3) changed for this: **Listen 8081**
4) saved file

-> Click **Config** button front of Apache.
1) Select **Apache (httpd-ssl.conf)** 
2) searched for this line: **Listen 443** 
3) changed for this: **Listen 444**
4) saved file

I can run xammp from port 8081
http://localhost:8081/
You have to give port number you gave to enter the localhost
Hope this helps you to understand what is happening.

Comment: Does anybody explain what kind of change this update lead to. What really happens?

Comment: Hi, you are running Apache in the same port as Skype.
Skype uses 443 port for default so as Apache, so if you change the port you will be able to use Apache without error.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when xampp was installed on windows 10.

> www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name

So I opened `httpd-ssl.conf` file in xampp folder and changed the following line

```
ServerName www.example.com:443
```

To

```
ServerName localhost
```

And the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I think killing the process which is uses that port is more easy to handle than changing the ports in config files. Here is how to do it in Windows. You can follow same procedure to Linux but different commands.
Run command prompt as Administrator. Then type below command to find out all of processes using the port.

```
netstat -ano
```

There will be plenty of processes using various ports. So to get only port we need use `findstr` like below (here I use port 80)

```
netstat -ano | findstr 80
```

this will gave you result like this

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7964
```

Last number is the process ID of the process. so what we have to do is kill the process using PID we can use `taskkill` command for that.

```
taskkill /PID 7964 /F
```

Run your server again. This time it will be able to run. This can uses for Mysql server too.

Comment: You question is not clear.
Are you asking "whether system is the one listening to the port"?

Answer (score 1):

> www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

I was getting this error when trying to start Apache, there is no error with Apache. It's an dependency error on windows 8 - probably the same for 7. Just right click and run as Admin :)

If you're still getting an error check your Antivirus/Firewall is not blocking Xampp or port 443.

Answer (score 0):

After changing main port from 80 to 8080 you have to change the config in XAMPP control panel as I show in the images:

1)
[image]

2)
[image]

3)
[image]

Then restart the service and that's it !