# Error 500 - Internal Server Error - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to install cms boostrap and after installation i had this problem. I tried everything. Thanks.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the apache error log and paste last errors here?

It is usually found here on /var/log/apache2, so executing the next command should display the last lines of that file:
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

Searching "www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name " i have found some links which could be a good point for you to start having a look:

- [error running apache after xampp install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097498/error-running-apache-after-xampp-install)
- https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/486973/problem-with-xampp-apache-and-htaccess
- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/solved-xampp-apache-error

Hope it helps