# Apache will not start after upgrading PHP7 on Xampp

Tags: xampp, php-7

I've been trying to upgrade to PHP7 on xampp, but when I try to restart Apache, I just get:

```
0:38:00  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
0:38:01  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
0:38:01  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
0:38:01  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
0:38:01  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
0:38:01  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
0:38:01  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
0:38:01  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
0:38:01  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
0:38:01  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

I've already updated:
httpd-xampp.conf with the correct path and naming. But no luck.

Also tried switching ports, and don't have skype. I don't think it's a port issue since everything's working fine when I use php5. Everything suggested here:

[Apache is not running from XAMPP Control Panel ( Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel-error-apache-shutdown-unexpect)

Apache Logs:

```html
[Tue Mar 21 02:48:54.551995 2017] [core:notice] [pid 10852:tid 280] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Mar 21 02:48:54.987020 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10852:tid 280] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10256
[Tue Mar 21 02:48:55.611056 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10256:tid 292] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 21 02:48:55.927074 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10256:tid 292] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 21 02:48:56.062081 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10256:tid 292] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Already tried the solutions mentioned here:
[error running apache after xampp install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097498/error-running-apache-after-xampp-install)

But also no luck.

Comment: check out the apache logs, after upgrading, are your sure that you have disabled the php5 apache module and enabled php7 apache module ?

Comment: @hassan Added Apache logs above. Still no luck on finding resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I did the xampp php upgrade from 5.4 to 7 according to this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdR8qHXpyHE

After the Apache restart I got the same errors.
I edited the httpd-xampp.conf: changed all the php5 stuffs for the php7 relevants.
Then I tried to start apache again.

Apache has started.
Hope this helps!

Br,
Lez