# Virtualhost is not accessible

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I tried to use a virtualhost on my new local projetc, but each time, I got an inaccessible page.

Here is my different configuration files :

my host :

```
    127.0.0.1       motbase.loc
```

my httpd-vhost.conf :

```
    #NameVirtualHost *:80

    #Moteur de base
#Moteur de base
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName motbase.loc
    ServerAlias www.motbase.loc
    DocumentRoot "P:\xampp\htdocs\moteur-de-base\web"
    <Directory "P:\xampp\htdocs\moteur-de-base\web">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My index.php file is in the web folder.

My Apache error logs :

```
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:51.913833 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.008083 2018] [core:warn] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH00098: pid file P:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.010089 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.027134 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH00455: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.027134 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Nov  3 2017 10:30:36
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.027134 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH00094: Command line: 'p:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d P:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.030142 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7144:tid 608] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 19264
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release P:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:20
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.548521 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 19264:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.628734 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 19264:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:57:52.647785 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 19264:tid 648] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I also tried with 8081 port but this is the same.

If you have any idea of what is wrong and if you need any other informations, just ask :)

Thanks you !

Comment: maybe helps [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097498/error-running-apache-after-xampp-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097498/error-running-apache-after-xampp-install)

Comment: I uninstalled Skype, changed my port and run xampp as administrator but still doesn't work :(