# XAMPP wont start

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm having an issue with Xampp, I have changed my port to listen to 8080 and I still cant connect. Here is my error:

```
12:37:13  [Apache]  Problem detected!
12:37:13  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
12:37:13  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:37:13  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:37:13  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different      port
12:37:13  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
```

Also I am having trouble with starting mySql

```
12:39:59  [mysql]   Problem detected!
12:39:59  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server     5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
12:39:59  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:39:59  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:39:59  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
12:39:59  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Edit: PID 4 is used by the System, however i have changed the port to listen to port 8080, but no success.

There is also no process uses port 3306 and im unsure why mySql wont start

Comment: Have you got Skype or any other software of that type running?

Comment: No, I made sure of that :p

Comment: hmmm.... try this link http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Comment: better yet.... here is a stack overflow link to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12

Comment: sounds like it is already running and you are trying to start it a second time.

Comment: Nope. I have just restarted my PC

Comment: Run `netstat -a -b` in a command prompt, it will tell you which port is used by which program. Even though it's pretty clear with the mysql port.

Comment: EEventManager.exe is using port 3306, and port 80 says "cannot obtain ownership of that information"

Comment: How you changed apache port ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12