# Unable to install XAMPP properly or unable to start apache and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

1. I am very new to PHP, just started learning.
2. After i installed XAMPP, i cant find the control panel in all programs, when i open the control panel from the folder that i installed and run as admin i see below message:

[error when run as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btlnh.png)
3. I have changed the apachi listining port from 80 to 8080 but still i see port 80 not available message. i have searched for most of avaiable resource and tried it but nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4! 12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12)

Comment: Hi, i have already changed the listing port on httpd.config. but still apache does not start. i have attached the screen shot above

Answer (score 0):

Ah well, if you are using Skype it also runs on port 80 by default, so you need to stop all Skype processes and try to run apache. Otherwise go into Skype's preferences and change the default port.