# The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8081 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured

Tags: tomcat, port, windows-10-desktop

Can I kill process id:4(System image) using 8081 port. I want to run tomcat at this 8081 port? Detail of process is shown in below image.
[image]

Comment: So stop the service that is using port 8081, or use a different port.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can I stop System service that is using 8081 port as shown in above image. Are you sure windows would not crash or ran into some problem? Can you explain  what is meant by "System Service" and what will be the effect after stopping this service?

Answer (score 0):

PID 4 doesn't itself handle any traffic, but rather implements an HTTP and HTTPS multiplexer on behalf of other processes allowing them to share an incoming port(s).

Do `netsh http show servicestatus` to see the PID(s) that is(are) *really* responsible, and deal with it(them) as applicable. You can also use `net stop http` to find out the service(s) that *could* be using it, but that doesn't show definitely which one(s) *currently* is(are). For some possibilities see:

https://superuser.com/questions/1188629/the-system-process-is-listening-on-port-443-and-i-cant-find-what-service-is
https://superuser.com/questions/43307/why-is-system-process-listening-on-port-80
https://serverfault.com/questions/100452/make-iis6-not-listen-on-one-ip
[How do I free my port 80 on localhost Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788348/how-do-i-free-my-port-80-on-localhost-windows)
[XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4! 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12)