# Issues with localhost:8080 port in my XAMPP - Visual Studio code stack

Tags: visual-studio-code, localhost

After I've updated my Windows 10 my XAMPP got "Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!" error. I googled and found that "80 port" related issues is a pretty much common one. It can be resolved by replacing port number in XAMPP Apache (httpd.conf) file in

```
Listen 8080
```

and

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

lines. This is what I made and my Apache began to work again.

But after I launched my project page from VS code, the browser (I use Chrome) returned **"This localhost page can’t be found"** error.
I thought this is because the root didn't contain :8080 after "localhost". I added :8080 after "localhost" in Chrome address bar and everything stared working.

I think that the reason is somewhere in VS code settings. I added :8080 in VS code settings but after I click "Open PHP/HTML/JS in browser" the pages of my project are still being opened without :8080 after "localhost" in the root in the address bar.

[check out here and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pGBX.png) 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VweCe.png)

I've already spent the half of the day to find out how can I resolve the issue but I think I couldn't manage without an external help.
Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I spent up to 3 days until found the answer.
In my case this one helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/22058569/14882824