# Xampp apache won't run after previous Apache installation

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've installed Xampp because the Apache module that I installed earlier won't let me use curl. However, I get these errors as a result and I can't start apache from xampp:

```
10:47:30 AM  [main]     All prerequisites found
10:47:30 AM  [main]     Initializing Modules
10:47:30 AM  [Apache]   Apache Service detected with wrong path
10:47:30 AM  [Apache]   Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
10:47:30 AM  [Apache]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
10:47:30 AM  [Apache]   Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
10:47:30 AM  [Apache]   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
10:47:30 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
10:47:30 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
```

I tried adding the C:\xampp\apache\bin directory to the path and commented out the line that refers to the port used by the original Apache module (C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.conf):

```
 # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
 # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
 # directive.
 #
 # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
 # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
 #
 #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
 #Listen 80
```

Here are my path variables:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static; C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\PHP;C:\PHP\ext;C:\Apache24\bin;C:\xampp\apache\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\xampp\apache\bin"
```

I don't think it's gonna help me solve the problem but should I remove the original Apache directory from the path to solve this?

Comment: Yes. you should absolutely remove the previous reference to the Apache Service within your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to un-install everything given from xampp previous installation. And why is there an Apache folder in the `c:\` drive? Everything controlled by `xampp` will reside on `c:\xampp` directory. It contains `mysql, php, ftp, apache` and the entire bundle of software in `xampp` folder.

Delete everything with the `apache un-install tool first`. If its not found, do it manually, make sure apache is turned off so you don't get permission error when deleting. Then clear your path vars relating to apache and other `xampp` software components.

Also run xampp un-install program, it will clean up your previous installation residue including settings. (Double check the `c:\` folder and make sure there isn't any xampp folder, if any delete before the new installation)

You don't need to reboot your pc. Run the xampp installer again, you should be good to go considering you've un-installed previous stand alone Apache installation and xampp un-install and none of the folders live on the `c:\` drive and cleared your settings before the new installation.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that in a bit and let you know. I want to see if I can resolve the curl issue first on the original apache installation and if not, I will try this out.

Comment: Sure. You need the curl dll file in the extensions folder and you need to un-comment load extension php curl in the php.ini file then start apache from the xampp control panel to take changes into affect. Then pull up a black php page with phpinfo() function to check if the module is loaded, you'll see php curl enabled. If you're on the command line, you can issue > php -m and you should see curl on the list.

Comment: Yeah, curl calls are not working on the original apache installation so I guess I'll be using xampp for now. If anyone wants to refer to the curl call issue I have on my original installation, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996065/curl-calls-are-not-working-on-apache-php

Comment: you should only run one copy of apache since xampp has apache and enabling curl could be hanging on both ends.

Comment: Ok. I uninstalled original apache installation with "httpd.exe -k uninstall" and removed php and apache directories. I uninstalled xampp as well and then reinstalled. I encountered an issue when I launched xampp that similar to what this post states (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245474/apache-wont-run-in-xampp). So, my resolution was to relaunch xampp as administrator and I was able to launch it with no problem. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: np. which makes sense, depending on how you have your system setup, you need admin rights to execute things that apache does while it starts up. in a way in the windows world you're giving it sudo power which is equivalent to run as Administrator.