# XAMPP windows 7 - Apache shutdown unexpectedly... suddenly, and I do not wyy

Tags: xampp

I have on my laptop installed XAMPP. It was running for years… (v3.1.x, not the latest version) No problem at all.
Suddenly saterday evening I try to start the appache server by xampp control panel and I get the next error:

```
19:33:25  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
19:33:25  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  
19:33:25  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method   
19:33:25  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check  
19:33:25  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues  
19:33:25  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this  
19:33:25  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I have been googling and searching.

- I have Skype already disabled port 80/443 at the time I have
  installed Skype

  - I have changed httpd.conf; Listen 8080 in stead of 80; Listen 4433 in    stead of 443
  - I have also been searching who is using port 80 by Netstat xampp    panel. I do not see any PID process with porth 80
  - I have activate “show debub information”, but I don’t see information of an error.
  - There is nothing written in the error.log.  When it happen it was 5-12-2015 and I the last lines in the error logs are from
    3-12-2015.
  - I have downloaded the latest XAMPP version (zip), unzipped first put    it in a different directory. Same error
  - I have tried to look in the windows event viewer but I couldn't find anything or I'm not looking in the good log item in windows
  - I have done all these command with the cmd:

net stop http
netstat –abno
netstat -abno | find ":80"
netstat -abno | find ":443"
netstat -a –b
netstat –ano

Not a result that port 80 is used. So it seems to me that it is **NOT** a port issue.

It is on window 7 system, bitdefender total security 2015, wich is already installed in july of this year.
I download always the XAMPP zip version and start xampp always by the control panel not as a service.

**Has anybody an idea what has happen or what could be happen?**

I have also read these links
[XAMPP, Apache - Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788348/how-do-i-free-my-port-80-on-localhost-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245474/apache-wont-run-in-xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: run `procmon` while you try to launch xampp. Check if the Visual C++ runtime is correctly installed.